# unable to install bootstrap in VS code Terminal

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am getting this error-----
C:\Users\agupta635\OneDrive - DXC Production\Desktop\angular training\Angular\angular-app>npm i bootstrap@4.6.0
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\agupta635\OneDrive - DXC Production\Desktop\angular training\Angular\angular-app\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\node_modules\ajv-keywords
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\agupta635\OneDrive - DXC Production\Desktop\angular training\Angular\angular-app\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\node_modules.ajv-keywords-iVlMWUIP
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, rename 'C:\Users\agupta635\OneDrive - DXC Production\Desktop\angular training\Angular\angular-app\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\node_modules\ajv-keywords' -> 'C:\Users\agupta635\OneDrive - DXC
Production\Desktop\angular training\Angular\angular-app\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\node_modules.ajv-keywords-iVlMWUIP'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\agupta635\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-02-23T06_43_28_168Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Please write down the debug log.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.